# Unique Validation in Laravel 5.4 not working as intended for where() statement

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In this table, there are 3 main parameters:

```
"is_active" (BOOLEAN)
"position" (INT)
"id"
```

This is the Unique Rule

```
'position' => [
'required_if:is_active,true|integer|min:1',
Rule::unique('tablename')->where(function($query) { $query->where('is_active', '=', 'true')->where('id', '!=', $this->id); }),
],
```

This rule is supposed to make sure that the `position` parameter to be unique among the data that have `is_active` set to `true`. Current issue is that this rule has been ignored, and I'm able to save the update/edit function even though by right is should have failed this validation.

> id=1, position=1, is_active=true

> id=2, position=2, is_active=true

when I change the position from 2 to 1, as shown above, it should show an error message, instead of being successful. but it isn't the case.

EDIT: `$this` attribute

```
ParameterBag {#1862
  #parameters: array:13 [
    "is_active" => "1"
    "order" => "2"
  ]
}
```

Note: This is in Laravel 5.4 and please do not suggest me to upgrade to Laravel 8, etc.

Comment: Does the rule work without the `where`?

Comment: yes. I have just realized there is an issue with the "$this" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, `$this->id` you are use is `id` which is available in the parameters.

so, you can achieve in 2 ways

1. use unique validation rules, ex...
   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique

```
'position' => [
    'required_if:is_active,true|integer|min:1',
    'unique:tablename,columnname,yourIDvalue',
],
```

2. you can use `use` in the function, like this...

```
'position' => [
    'required_if:is_active,true|integer|min:1',
    Rule::unique('tablename')->where(function($query) use ($yourIDvalue) {
        $query->where('is_active', '=', 'true')->where('id', '!=', $yourIDvalue);
    }),
],
```